# SCons appears to build the same section multiple times

Tags: scons

When building, SCons appears to build a .os, then a .a, and then add the -fPIC to build a .so. Is there some way to trim down this build time?

Does SCons run in parallel like "make -j"?

Answer (score 0):

SCons does support parallel builds using the -j/--jobs option.

In your example, you cannot build those three items - the .os, the .a and the .so in parallel.  First, the .c or .cpp file has to be compiled to an .os, then the .os is compiled into a .a, then the .a is linked into the .so.  That's basic compiler and linker processing.